# Unity3D: Array out of range

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wrote a function that gets the triangles from a mesh in Unity3d but I get an "array is out of range" error. This is the function:

```
static Vector3[,] CreateTriangles(Mesh _mesh)
{
    // In this function I make an 2d array and then I store the triangles in there.
    int TTriangleAmount = _mesh.triangles.Length / 3;
    int TTrianglePoints = _mesh.triangles.Length;
    int TTriangleSize = 3;
    Vector3[,] TTriangleArray = new Vector3[TTriangleAmount,TTriangleSize];

    for(int i = 0; i < TTrianglePoints ; i += TTriangleSize)
    {
        TTriangleArray[i,0] = _mesh.vertices[_mesh.triangles[i + 0]];
        TTriangleArray[i,1] = _mesh.vertices[_mesh.triangles[i + 1]];
        TTriangleArray[i,2] = _mesh.vertices[_mesh.triangles[i + 2]];
    }
    return TTriangleArray;
}
```

I can't seem to figgure out why it is out of range. Can anyone see the flaw I made?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem! Index *i* is going up by 3 every time. But then I cannot use *i* to find the position to place the triangle in the first dimension of the triangle array. So to get that position I just devided *i* by 3 to get the right position and that fixes it!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FetchTriangleTest : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        Vector3[,] test = CreateTriangles(transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh);
    }

    static Vector3[,] CreateTriangles(Mesh _mesh)
    {
        // In deze functie maak in een twee demensionale array waar ik de triangles in opsla.
        int TTriangleAmount = _mesh.triangles.Length / 3;
        int TTrianglePoints = _mesh.triangles.Length;
        int TTriangleSize = 3;
        Vector3[,] TTriangleArray = new Vector3[TTriangleAmount,TTriangleSize];

        for(int i = 0; i < TTrianglePoints ; i += TTriangleSize)
        {
            int triIndex = i / 3;
            TTriangleArray[triIndex,0] = _mesh.vertices[_mesh.triangles[i + 0]];
            TTriangleArray[triIndex,1] = _mesh.vertices[_mesh.triangles[i + 1]];
            TTriangleArray[triIndex,2] = _mesh.vertices[_mesh.triangles[i + 2]];
        }
        return TTriangleArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would look at is your TTriangleAmount variable. Looks like you have a two dimensional array of type Vector3, and you're setting the length of the first dimension to TTriangleAmount.
TTriangleAmount looks like it's set to the number of triangles divided by three, so if you have less than three triangles you get 0, if you have three triangles in your mesh you get 1, and so on and so forth.

You're looping through the triangle points, which, at this point, there are about three times as many points as the value of the TTriangleAmount, so you can probably get rid of TTriangleAmount's '/ 3' or just do away with it entirely and use TTrianglePoint to set the size of the first dimension in your Vector3 array.